# Firebase - Best way to structure user posts and posts to a feed

Tags: database, firebase, database-design, firebase-realtime-database

Here is my scenario that I need help with. I have a "feed" for a specific location that has `posts`. `posts` are created by `users` and anyone can see a `post` from a specific location.

So essentially: user writes post -> gets submitted to location -> user can also view their own posts on their profile -> anyone can view posts from a location.

So here is the way I thought it was best to structure:

[image]

(sorry if the syntax is bad I'm just playing around at the moment). So essentially, I would send ALL post data that the user created to the location AND the user's profile.. Is that bad practice? Doubling the size of the db as well as keeping both posts up to date.. If the score (i.e upvoting/downvoting) changes for the post I would have to update in both sections...

Is there a better way? Please let me know! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your requirement correctly, you should have a table for posts, a table for users and a table for locations.

A post is written by a user who assigns it to a location.

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful!